# Access to the path 'InterfaceStubGenerator.BuildTasks.dll' is denied after clearing nuget cache

Tags: nuget, dotnet-cli

I've just cleared all my nuget caches using:

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```

But now when i try to restore/build I get the following error

```
C:\dev\noddy\src\noddy.Api>dotnet build
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\NuGet.targets(102,5): error : Access to the path 'InterfaceStubGenerator.BuildTasks.dll' is denied. [C:\dev\noddy\src\noddy.Api\noddy.Api.csproj]
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Close other dotnet.exe processes. May be initialized in other IDEs (VS, VS Code, Rider & e.t.c)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I recommend the following steps:

- Restart your PC or laptop. This action can help stop any processes that might be locking files, including the DLL file in question.
- Execute `dotnet clean` on your solution to clear the build outputs, followed by `dotnet restore` to reinstate the NuGet packages.
- Ensure that the `InterfaceStubGenerator` is correctly set up in your project.
- Execute `dotnet clean` on your solution to clear the build outputs, followed by `dotnet restore` to reinstate the NuGet packages.
- Verify your permissions for the `InterfaceStubGenerator.BuildTasks.dll` file. Right-click on the file, select Properties, and review the permissions under the Security tab.
- Attempt to build as an administrator. This grants you elevated privileges that might be necessary for certain file operations.
- If necessary, remove and then re-add the package. Also, verify that the file isn't corrupted.
- Update or reinstall the .NET SDK to address any compatibility or corruption issues.
- Manually delete the `obj` and `bin` folders from your project.
- Temporarily disable your antivirus software, or add the file to the antivirus exceptions list to prevent interference during the build process.
- Utilize Task Manager or Resource Monitor to identify any running processes that might be using the file. If you find such processes, terminate them and then attempt to rebuild.

These steps should help in addressing the file access issue you're encountering.